# How can I Choose Specifc Users to Log Into my Javascript SPA in Azure AD?

Tags: javascript, azure-active-directory, single-page-application, azure-ad-msal

I'm using a **Javascript SPA** to return a query from Microsoft Graph through the Azure AD application, and it works just fine!

The **problem** is when I try to loggout from the application, it says I was successfully logged out but if try to **log in with another user, it logs into the previous one**, in this case, me, without even asking for password. 
I needed that this application could log in just few people in my organization, but anyone with ***"@example.com"*** can access my application, without the need to be signed to it or not.

I've already **cleared the browser's cache and cookies** and it doesn't work. Already configured the app to store the cache in the session but it also failed.

**The code I'm using is available in:**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-javascript-spa

The only differences are that I'm using another querys instead the *"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me"* and the permissions needed to get them.

**I just needed a way to choose specific people to log into the application instead of all the organization and to fix this logout problem.**

Comment: "You need to make sure this token is validated by your backend server to guarantee that the token was issued to a valid user for your application." Have you done so?

Comment: I think not, I just downloaded the solution in the azure quickstart and changed the permissions used and the graph query, but I thought the msal library already did everything. If this procedure you mentioned is needed, can you guide me on doing it?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you well, I believe your solution is the option `select_account`.

Here is a code snippet to illustrate:

```
const clientApplication = new Msal.UserAgentApplication(config);

const loginRequest = {
    scopes: [config.webApiScope],
    prompt: "select_account",
}

clientApplication.loginPopup(loginRequest).then(function (loginResponse) {
    //your code
});
```

Comment: No, it didn't work, it just keep the same behavior, I can't loggout and when I try to log in with another account that is in my organization, it don't ask this other account's password and log into my user.

Comment: @Breno.Nunes maybe there is a problem on you logout flow then. If I may, I would suggest taking a look at this sample: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-aspnet-webapi-onbehalfof. I tested it and it always asks me the password on the three accounts that I tested. One exception is my windows account, that doesnt require password because it uses the operation system credentials.